# How do I run these js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I am sorry this is a silly question but was just looking for a quick short answer. I have no coding experience. The screenshot attached is a list of folders and files for a frontend website. How and what files do I need to run to see a page?

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV9Bw.png)

Comment: Probably just node. Open your server.js and look for a line that says app.listen. This should include a port. Then from term you can `$node server.js` and visit http://localhost:8080` replace 8080 w port in app.listen line of server.js file

Comment: I have the following: 

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log(`Server Started. Listening on port 3000`);

How do visit localhost:8080?

Comment: open safari/chrome and just type in the address bar  `http://localhost:3000`